# Swift AVPlayer How To Stop Automatically When Audio Finished

Tags: swift, audio, uikit, avplayer

I've created a button to play audio (streaming from a link) with AVPlayer in Swift. How to stop the audio automatically when the audio time is finished?

Here is some of my code :

```
var player : AVPlayer?
url = URL(string: "https://cdn.islamic.network/quran/audio/128/ar.alafasy/162.mp3")
let playerItem:AVPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url!)
player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)

player?.play()
```

For example, in this URL (https://cdn.islamic.network/quran/audio/128/ar.alafasy/162.mp3), the audio length is 19 seconds. So after 19 seconds I play the audio, the audio must stop.

Thank you :)

Comment: You can use AVAudioPlayer and confirm to its audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying delegate. Stop playing when this delegate is called.

Comment: @Zain AVAudioPlayer will download the audio before you play it. Here I won't download the audio :D

So I use AVPlayer to avoid downloading audio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the NSNotificationCenter Observer

```
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "playerDidFinishPlaying:", name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: item)

    player?.play()
```

and stop player in this function

```
    func playerDidFinishPlaying(note: NSNotification) {
        // Your code here
        player?.pause()
        player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: nil)
    }
```